# pdfjs-dist package Cannot find name 'OffscreenCanvasRenderingContext2D' Error In Angular 14, Dot Net Core 5

Tags: angular14, pdfjs-dist

dotnet core 5
Angular 14

### Installed

npm install pdfjs-dist

import * as pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist';

### then Error:-

Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices: Error: Error: node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/text_layer.d.ts:119:41 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'OffscreenCanvasRenderingContext2D'.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices: Error: 119         ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D | OffscreenCanvasRenderingContext2D | null;
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices: Error: